# Limit of outer measure of set intersection

Tags: measure-theory

This is a question on Axler's book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis available here: http://measure.axler.net/

> Prove that $|A|=\lim_{k\to\infty} |A\cap [-k,k]|$ for all $|A|\subset \mathbb{R}$.

where $|\cdot|$ is the outer measure. Essentially I think that by the definition given in that book, we have

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|A\cap[-k,k]|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\inf\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty \ell(I_j):I_1,\text{... are open sets s.t. } A\cap[-k,k] \subset\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j\right)$$

And I feel like we can just say the $\lim \inf$ of this is $|A|$, but I can't really justify why.